# Usar variables privadas en otra clase NO principal

Tags: java, get, set

¿como usar variables privadas desde una clase no principal? ¿y como se llama este proceso para buscarlo en pildorasInformaticas o en codigoFacilito?
Hola, tengo un proyecto/practica, cuya clase principal es Pildoras_NivelesPoder, el cual consiste en los Niveles de poder tipo dragon ball.

```
public class Pildoras_NivelesPoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pildoras_Guerrero fighter1 = new Pildoras_Guerrero();
        }
}
```

Aquí se ingresa la salud y en base a eso desde la clase Pildoras_Guerrero se calcula el nivel de energia (salud*2) y los distintos ataques que consisten en porcentajes de la salud: uno(1%), tres(3%), seis(6%), diez(10%), quince(15%), cuarto(25%), medio(50%) y ultimate(100%), todas esas variables son privadas y enteras.
p

```
ublic class Pildoras_Guerrero {
    private String nombre;
    private int salud;
    private int energia;
    private int uno;
    private int tres;
    private int seis;
    private int diez;
    private int quince;
    private int cuarto;
    private int medio;
    private int ultimate;
    
    private String habilidad;
    
    
    
    public Pildoras_Guerrero()
    {
        nombre="desconocido";
        salud=0;
        energia=0;
        uno=0;
        tres=0;
        seis=0;
        diez=0;
        quince=0;
        cuarto=0;
        medio=0;
        ultimate=0;
    }
    
                        //setter nombre
    public void sel_nombre()
    {
        nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese Nombre");
        
    }
    
                        //getter nombre
    public String com_nombre()
    {
        return "nombre:"+ nombre;
    }
    
                        //setter salud
    public void ing_salud()
    {
        salud=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ("Ingrese salud total"));
        
    }
    
    /*
    public boolean validacion(String s)
    {
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            return true;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    */
    
                    //getter salud
    public String com_salud()
    {
        return "salud: "+salud;
    }
    
                    //setter energia
    public void est_energia()
    {
        energia=salud*2;
    }
    
                    //getter energia
    public String com_energia()
    {
        return "Energia: "+energia;
    }
                    //setter uno
    public void est_uno()
    {
        uno=(int) (salud*.01);
    }
    
                    //getter uno
    public String com_uno()
    {
        return "1%:  "+uno;
    }
    
                    //setter tres
    public void est_tres()
    {
        tres=(int)(salud*.03);
    }
    
                    //getter tres
    public String com_tres()
    {
        return "3%:  "+tres;
    }
    
                        //setter seis
    public void est_seis()
    {
        seis=(int)(salud*.06);
    }
    
                    //getter seis
    public String com_seis()
    {
        return "6%:  "+seis;
    }
    
                        //setter diez
    public void est_diez()
    {
        diez=(int)(salud*.1);
    }
    
                    //getter diez
    public String com_diez()
    {
        return "10%: "+diez;
    }
    
                        //setter quince
    public void est_quince()
    {
        quince=(int)(salud*.15);
    }
    
                    //getter quince
    public String com_quince()
    {
        return "15%: "+quince;
    }
    
                        //setter cuarto
    public void est_cuarto()
    {
        cuarto=salud/4;
    }
    
                    //getter cuarto
    public String com_cuarto()
    {
        return "25%: "+cuarto;
    }
    
    
                        //setter medio
    public void est_medio()
    {
        medio=salud/2;
    }
    
                    //getter medio
    public String com_medio()
    {
        return "50%: "+medio;
    }
    
                        //setter ultimate
    public void est_ultimate()
    {
        ultimate=salud;
    }
    
                    //getter ultimate
    public String com_ultimate()
    {
        return "Ultimate: "+ultimate;
    }
}
```

El problema es que quiero crear una clase Pildoras_Ira el cual use esos valores anteriores ya calculados para aumentarlos en un 10% y no puedo usarlas en el constructor de esta clase como si fueran los valores por defecto

```
public class Pildoras_Ira{

    private int irauno;
    private int iratres;
    private int iraseis;
    private int iradiez;
    private int iraquince;
    private int iracuarto;
    private int iramedio;
    private int iraultimate;
    
    public Pildoras_Ira()
    {
        /*como declare las variables como privadas en guerrero no puedo igualar
        los valores de ira con los normales si no posse estado iracundo
        */
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero ya encapsulaste las variables... a que te referis??? como pasar una clase a otra?

Comment: Vaya, siento haber entendido mal la pregunta, retiraré mi respuesta, un saludo y muchas gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score -1):

A la pregunta:
¿como usar variables privadas desde una clase no principal? ¿y como se llama este proceso para buscarlo en pildorasInformaticas o en codigoFacilito?

Respondo:
Se llama **encapsulación** y define que las variables privadas (*private*) no se pueden acceder desde otras clases (solo dentro de la misma clase). Si necesitas poder acceder a esas variables desde una clase distinta, tienes dos opciones: hacerlas publicas (public) o protegidas (protected).

***En conclusión:***
Si las declaras **private** puedes acceder a las variables solo desde dentro de la misma clase.

Si las declaras **protected** puedes acceder a las variables desde clases que estén en el mismo paquete o por sus subclases (herencia).

Si las declaras **public** puedes acceder a esas variables desde cualquier clase.

Saludos!

Comment: Esto como respuesta no sería aceptable, lo fueras puesto como un comentario mejor. La verdad lo que le dices creo que ya lo debe haber escuchado y aun no logra captar bien el proceso como sería.

Comment: O sea, tu me calificas mal porque supones que esto no le va a servir a quién preguntó? Pienso que deberías dejar que quién pregunta sea el que diga si le sirve una respuesta o no.

Comment: perdona, pero te estoy comentando algo, no puedes asegurar que la mala calificación te la doy yo. Y si es el caso, la daría porque das como respuesta esto que podría ser un comentario. Si quieres anexale ejemplos o enlaces que le guíen mejor, eso se tomaría como una respuesta mejor

Comment: Pero quien pregunta ya encapsulo sus variables. No esta claro cual es el problema.. esta respuesta no esta mal, solo que no ataca el problema de OP, que a simple vista, no se sabe cual es....